# How to write error message on sides of textbox, without using any other tag in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to display an error message on side or below of textbox. 
In current scenario, the textbox is validated for isnumeric().

The message should be "Please enter correct value".

HTML

```
  NOK: <input data-require-numeric="" type="text" id="finalComments2" name="finalComments2" /> //here error message to be displayed<br>
  NOK: <input data-require-numeric="" type="text" id="finalComments2" name="finalComments2" /> //here error message to be displayed<br>
```

Jquery:

```
$('input[type="text"][data-require-numeric]').on("change keyup paste", function() {
```

I do not want to use any other tag, just want to adjust text on base of input tag only.

So how to 1) Write text on Right of Textbox, 
2) Below textbox, 
3) Above Textbox and 
4) Left of Textbox.

Fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/poofkgd4/

Comment: You could also just change the text inside the text box to an error message. If that works?

Comment: @User3735633
Not preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `after` to add text after textbox:

```
$('#finalComments2').after('My Message');
```

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/after/

To add text before textbox you can use `before`:

```
$('#finalComments2').before('My Message');
```

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/before/

To write to **Below** and **Above** the textbox you can use `<br />` inside `after` and `before` respectively.

Comment: This will add message after every time event fires. So we need to remove that and add message again, How to do that?

Comment: @fatherazrael Then you should use element like `span` and add/remove from it

Comment: dont we have any way with which i can find that there is text "My Message "after that element and i stop appending text, if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
  var someParentElement = $("#parent");
  var div = $('<div id="error-text' + textBoxNum + '">error</div>');

  div.css({
     position: 'absolute',
     'font-size': 20,
     top: 10,
     bottom: 10
  });

  someParentElement.append(div);
```

You can remove them by using $("error-text1").remove();

Comment: obviously css is adjusted to the positioning that suites your case. Because the position is relative to the parent element.

Comment: Could you please provide jfiddle for it?